# Type of $_GET variable

Tags: php, url, get

I have this rewriterule in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Then, when I check type of `$_GET['url']`, is always a string.

I interested to know whether or not it's possible, to write in the browser's address bar some magic symbols (or something like this) and obtain in `$_GET['url']` an other type (not string)?

Or will the type of `$_GET` always be `string`?

Comment: It is always a string, why would you want anything else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure PHP dynamically knows whether or not it should be a string or not.

You cannot declare it's type.

Comment: In PHP, this should write 2: `1 + "1"`. PHP is loosely typed.

Comment: I not want something else, I want that `$_GET` always will be `string`, I am just scare, that hacker or some bad boy, dont pass me something else type from URL :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do this:

```
 index.php?url=asd&url[]=asd //asd&url[]=asd being the dynamic part
```

Then `$_GET['url']` will be an array.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you take from `$_GET` will always be a string.

Comment: Do you have a source or an example to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` parameters will always be strings.

But you could check if your variable is a number, and then use a cast:

```
if (is_numeric($_GET['url'])) {
  $url = (int) $_GET['url'];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php