# Can a Query String Contain Anything Other than a String?

Tags: php, types, query-string

I was working on a project at my job and came upon this code:

```
$queryStringValue = $_GET['var'];

if ( is_string($queryStringValue) )
{
    // Do something.
}
```

My question: Is calling is_string() to check if the query string value is a string completely unnecessary? By definition, "query string" leads me to believe the data type can only be a string, thus making a call to is_string() redundant.

Am I right, or are there times when a different data type can be passed in a query string?

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: i didn't test it, but refer to the response of [Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389026/8010101) `$_GET["index"]` may be an array

Comment: Using `!is_array()`, while functionally equivalent in this case, would be more enlightening in your sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per PHP manual on [Variables From External Sources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) under "Determining variable types":

> HTTP being a text protocol, most, if not all, content that comes in Superglobal arrays, like $_POST and $_GET will remain as strings. PHP will not try to convert values to a specific type.

Again, in the manual's [FAQ: Arrays in HTML Form](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays), we read on arrays:

> To get your `<form>` result sent as an array to your PHP script you name the `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>` elements like this:
> `<input name="MyArray[]" /> ...`

This would turn into a query string `?MyArray[]=foo&MyArray[]=bar` etc., available as `$_GET['MyArray'][0]` and `$_GET['MyArray'][1]`. You can also use named keys; the query `?var[x]=one&var[y]=two` would result in the associative array `$_GET['var] = ['x' => 'one', 'y' => 'two']`; and `?var[x][]=deep` would become `$_GET['var']['x'] = ['deep']`, etc.

In addition, the [manual for `$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) notes the following:

> **Note:**
> The GET variables are passed through [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Then, see the signature of `urldecode`:

```
urldecode ( string $str ) : string
```

In other words, the function used for preprocessing `$_GET` values accepts a string and returns a string.   Evidently, when there's an array incoming, it will apply `urldecode` to each string value of that array instead. (If someone cares to find the PHP source code section responsible for generating `$_GET`, please share the link, will include it here.)

Note that an empty value, e.g. in `?foo&bar=1`, will *not* result in `[foo] NULL`, but rather in `[foo] string(0) ""`, in other words a zero-length `string`. Again, we get `[bar] string(1) "1"`. There's no type-casting of `get` or `post` values into integers, floats, booleans or null.

In conclusion, the possible datatypes received in `$_GET` are `string` and `array` (of strings; or further arrays; with the final, scalar "leaves" being strings). Of course, if you explicitly declare `$_GET['foo'] = null` or `$_GET['bar'] = 1` in your PHP code, then there will be integers and nulls. The above applies to variables parsed by PHP from external sources.

---

**Update:** While the above is true for all the *values* parsed from the query string, things are different for the *keys* PHP extracts from a query string. Suppose the following URL:

```
test.php?101=foo&202=bar&dev=ops
```

Now, what will `var_dump(array_keys($_GET))` return for the numeric keys? Integers, not strings:

```
array(3) {
    [0] · int(101)
    [1] · int(202)
    [2] · string(3) "dev"
}
```

This is in line with PHP's [standard casting of array keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php): *"Strings containing valid decimal integers, unless the number is preceded by a + sign, will be cast to the integer type.*". The following key cast will however not happen: *"Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated."* Because (as noted in [Variables from External Sources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)): *"Dots and spaces in [external] variable names are converted to underscores."*

---

### External Variable Typecasting: Summary

- A query string's **values** will always be *strings*, or *arrays* (of arrays) with strings as their final scalar values.
- A query string's **keys** will always be *strings*, excepting whole numbers (unsigned positive: `3`, signed negative: `-3`) that are cast as *integers* instead.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the explanation, examples and sources. 

Comment: thanks for you @Markus and thanks for GTS for this question, upvote for both :)

Comment: Seemed like this question wasn't ever definitively asked/answered on SO -- glad to oblige. :) On a footnote on external input datatypes, we have the case of AJAX requests sending JSON data in a POST request body. These won't appear in the superglobals, and need to be accessed via `php://input`. When `json_decode()`'d, such data will have the full spectrum of datatypes known to JSON. Here's an excellent Q/A with more details: [PHP “php://input” vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Comment: Added a note on *integer casting* that happens to numeric keys. Then, the complete conclusion is: **A query string's *values* will always be strings or arrays with strings. A query string's *keys* will always be strings, except for whole numbers that are cast as integers.**

Answer (score 1):

the query string itself is a `string`, but variables from it may be parsed as `string` or `array`:

`url.com?var=123` => var is string

`url.com?var[]=123&var[]=321` => var is an array

Answer (score -4):

Yes it contains.
It can have any type you want, including array, integers, floats etc..

Comment: **It can have any type** ? , give me an exemple how can contain an object ?

Comment: @GNassro I don't think he knows what he's talking about. ‍♂️

Comment: I want type `potato` (scalar). How to implement?!